# How to use change of variable to prove the expectation under Gaussian random variable equals the expectation under standard normal random variable.

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $\mathbf{x}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2 I)$ be a multivariate isotropic Gaussian random variable. And let $f(\mathbf{x})$ be a scalar-valued function. How could we apply change of variable technique to prove the follow result

$$
E_{\mathbf{x}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2 I)}[f(\mathbf{x})] = E_{\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)}[f(\mu + \epsilon\sigma)]
$$

By expanding the expectation on the left hand side with integral, we obtain

$
\begin{align*}
\int f(\mathbf{x}) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\big)^2\big) d\mathbf{x} 
&= \int f(\mu + \epsilon\sigma)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp\big(-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2\big) d\epsilon\cdot\sigma \\
&= E_{\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0, I)}[f(\mu + \epsilon\sigma)]
\end{align*}
$

Comment: Write down the integral first, then apply the linear (location-scale) transform as requested.

Comment: @BGM Thanks for the tip. I have updated some derivation I've made, could you help to check if it is correct ? In my memory, change of variables involves determinant, but it seems here it does not use that.

Comment: It is the same. The $\sigma$ at last is your "determinant". It seems that you have demonstrated how to do it in univariate case, from the notation of the integrand. Make sure you are doing the multivariate case (they are similar).